# How to host a webpage with AWS using IP address

Tags: server, apache2, ip, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a free tier AWS server. It is a Ubuntu server and I a beginner. I don't have a registered domain name, I have HTML and CSS code for the webpage. I normally see that I can access websites using their registered IP addresses. So are there any tutorials or documentation where I can find out how to deploy my HTML code to become a public website that can be accessed through the IP address that Amazon has provided.And note I haven't yet installed apache as I have not figured out what I should do with it. It would be great if someone can direct me to on how to make the HTML code public where anyone can view it using the IP address. Thanks in advance....Caio.

Comment: You should start learing using a non-public Virtual Box or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS, go to elastic IP address, and associate a public ip with your instance. Then, install a LAMP stack on your instance and upload your html files to /var/www/

The trick is the elastic public IP address.

For more on the Apache / LAMP etc, ask a more direct question about those, or follow a tutorial on Ubuntu.com